# Draw point on mouse click with Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, mouseevent, graphics2d

I'm working on a project in which I am trying to draw point on mouse click within a JPanel with Java Swing.

I save each time the clicked points coordinate in currentX and currentY and create an Ellipse2D List with those coordinates but it doesn't work.

Comment: Use either the `mousePressed` or `mouseReleased` method instead of the `mouseClicked` method.  Your double click has to have an extremely precise timing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it and it works! Below the solution:

```
package progetto;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author Anna
 */
public class MapDrawer extends JPanel{
    
    private List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public MapDrawer(){
        setBackground(new Color(23,99,8));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(Color.gray);
        for (Point p : points){
            g2.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 5, 5);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MapDrawer());
                frame.setSize(400,400);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Your MapDrawer class should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the desired size of your custom panel. Then after you add the panel to the frame and before you make the frame visible you invoke pack() on the frame. Now all the components will be displayed at their preferred size including the title bar and borders of the frame.